# [PHP]Find array of bytes in file & replace it

Tags: php, hex, byte

i would like to find array of bytes in opened file and replace it with another one.
Any idea how to do that ? :)

This is how i read something from the file, everything works.

```
$current_file = basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
$someInfoFromFile = 0;

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $current_file))
    {
        $fh = fopen($current_file, 'rw');
        fseek($fh, 1000);
        $someInfoFromFile = fread($fh, 2);
        fclose($fh);
                
        echo "Bytes read from file: " . $someInfoFromFile;
    }
}
```

example:

1. Find $Buffer1 = array(10, 30, 30, 10);
2. Replace it with $Buffer2 = array(20, 20, 20, 20);
3. Maybe return if found or not.

Answer (score 0):

[`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is binary safe, just make strings from your bytes. You can do this manually using the [`chr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function:

```
$search = chr(10) . chr(30) . chr(30) . chr(10);
$replace = chr(20) . chr(20) . chr(20) . chr(20);
```

Or build it from your array:

```
$search = pack('C*', ...$buffer1);
$replace = pack('C*', ...$buffer2);
```

Or maybe:

```
$search = join('', array_map('chr', $buffer1));
$replace = join('', array_map('chr', $buffer2));
```

Then:

```
$oldContents = file_get_contents($file); // or however you get it
$newContents = str_replace($search, $replace, $oldContents, $count);
echo "$count instances were replaced\n";
```

Comment: Any way of returning Address of array if its found?
Like
echo 'Array found at address: ' . $address_of_array;

Comment: [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: to be able to find anything in file i have to convert to hex2bin($src); thanks alot for help